# High Bush Blueberries with shriveled berries

Tags: fruits, blueberries

I have a some wild high bush blueberries in US/NH and there is one bush that needs a major pruning. In past years its produced fairly well but I've definitely noticed its bloomed out a lot this year but not many of the berries are making it all the way. Many of the berries are shriveling up as you can see in the picture. Is this simply because the bush is too old and needs a major prune (as it does and will happen this fall) or could this be another issue for the tree? Water? Diseases?

[image: berries]

Answer (score 1):

The photo indicates the bush has lost most of the leaves, which is typical if the soil has been too dry for longer periods.

Some diseases like [Monilinia vaccinii-corymbosi (Mummy berries)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Vaccinium_diseases) can cause shriveled berries too. Cut berries a half and look for traces inside the berries.

The photo shows healthy green berries. I suggest to water when needed until they are fully ripe. If they ripe as healthy berries, then the issue most likely was caused by dry conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Check the ph of your soil. Blueberries need very acidic soil. Try adding some ammonium sulphate ammonium nitrate, or sphagnum moss.